# Как из Exponent и Modulus получить открытый ключ RSA шифрования

Tags: rsa

Привет!

Как из значений Exponent и Modulus получить "открытый ключ" RSA шифрования, который можно передать получателю шифрованного сообщения. Чтобы сгенерировать закрытый и открытый ключи использую следующий код.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = RSA.ExportParameters(true);
var parameters = RSA.ToXmlString(false);
```

Получаю такие значения для открытого ключа:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>rg5eQetdxUvwy3fkIUmsTRkQB2iWAm5phCiMjqUB3AzQNJnVtQQIeM/x4RSdp1BiwmHLRO2OHrsiSzKAU2dlIL6cR8nhsvEaKGMEO6cPq8RwW6lgI8FByMV58vZK0axowjDfhBQ3jJCLpfKbA2wAWnzP1zls6Abpq3k3+15poq0=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

Обычно для открытого ключа ожидают увидеть что-то подобное (см.ниже).

```
    -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: PGP 8.1    
mQGiBEFpBTQRBADUtU3t8Xo8ciJrQMiMQeOfjjkknOsQppWy8IYDBBMeguofuHtN
SeCcU6MmhLdEq6eC9X8AFj6kb1SMi7yOdQTNBQmR76eOLtME3u8jtC66md9WWfz9
eNaUAt9k4YqhJQ4FPL5L5WiPLV9sp5rVqimGCGoHTR7dCzT5aWvnYYwDlwCg//fZ
kA4rKd+h9evtgCZhEGU3wIED+wZtzIMr
GBECAAYFAkFpBTQACgkQKqAivsw/P3crCACgyT8lyLozBJR9Byu9lvgN/h4D21YA
n0WTaM6UaY5yc2Hua8THrRcq3kS+=lOlr
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Каким образом нужно склеить значения Modulus и Exponent, чтобы получить верный открытый ключ ?

Например Modulus + Exponent:

```
rg5eQetdxUvwy3fkIUmsTRkQB2iWAm5phCiMjqUB3AzQNJnVtQQIeM/x4RSdp1BiwmHLRO2OHrsiSzKAU2dlIL6cR8nhsvEaKGMEO6cPq8RwW6lgI8FByMV58vZK0axowjDfhBQ3jJCLpfKbA2wAWnzP1zls6Abpq3k3+15poq0=AQAB
```

или так Exponent + Modulus:

```
AQABrg5eQetdxUvwy3fkIUmsTRkQB2iWAm5phCiMjqUB3AzQNJnVtQQIeM/x4RSdp1BiwmHLRO2OHrsiSzKAU2dlIL6cR8nhsvEaKGMEO6cPq8RwW6lgI8FByMV58vZK0axowjDfhBQ3jJCLpfKbA2wAWnzP1zls6Abpq3k3+15poq0=
```

Или как ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ключ RSA это пара (модуль, e-экспонента)
То, что вы привели в качестве образца для подражания - блок данных в Base64 формате. Как интерпретировать этот блок - проблема конкретной реализации криптографических функций (тут PGP ) и общего стандарта нет.